# How to get the line number where an Saxon XSLT compilation error occurs?

Tags: saxon

I am using Saxon PE 9.7.0.18.

I am compiling XSLT with code like:

```
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl;

...

StringBuilder errorString = new StringBuilder();
ErrorListener errorListener = new ErrorListener() {
    public void warning(TransformerException e) { 
        errorString.append("\nERROR: ").append(e.getMessageAndLocation()); }
    public void error(TransformerException e) { 
        errorString.append("\nWARN: ").append(e.getMessageAndLocation()); }
    public void fatalError(TransformerException e) { 
        errorString.append("\nFATAL: ").append(e.getMessageAndLocation()); }
};

TransformerFactoryImpl transformerFactory = 
    (TransformerFactoryImpl) TransformerFactory.newInstance(
        TransformerFactoryImpl.class.getName(), 
        DocumentGenerator.class.getClassLoader());
transformerFactory.setErrorListener(errorListener);
Templates templates = transformerFactory.newTemplates(new DOMSource(xslt));
xsltTransformerFactory = new XsltTransformerFactory() {
    @SneakyThrows(TransformerConfigurationException.class)
    @Override public Transformer newTransformer() { return templates.newTransformer(); }
};
Transformer transformer = xsltTransformerFactory.newTransformer();
```

Unfortunately, if the XSLT file is invalid, this yields errors such as:

```
FATAL: Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); 
   supplied value has item type xs:string
```

The XSLT files are sometimes thousands of lines long, as they are generated from another system. It would be very helpful to know what line such an error occurred. (Just now I did a "binary search" by repeatedly deleting half of the XSLT source file and seeing if the error still happened, to locate the offending line. Once I'd found the line the error in the XSLT file was pretty obvious!)

I'm sure the XSLT processor must know the line it's processing?

In the debugger I see that the `TransformerException` contains an `AttributeLocator` but both the `lineNumber` and `columnNumber` attributes are -1, which presumably explains why the `getMessageAndLocation()` method does not include the location.

I understand that there might be a compile-time flag during compilation of Saxon to influence this, but I didn't compile Saxon myself, I downloaded it from https://www.saxonica.com/download/java.xml when I purchased the PE edition.

How can I find out the line number of XSLT errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've supplied the stylesheet input from a DOM tree, and the DOM doesn't keep line numbers.

Unless you have a very good reason to use DOM, it's best avoided. The DOM is also bad at keeping track of base URI, which affects resolution of `xsl:include` and `xsl:import` among other things. Also, it's not thread-safe.

Use a `StreamSource` or `SAXSource` in preference.