# How do I get the line numbers of a saxonc XPath match?

Tags: python, xpath, saxon, xpath-2.0, saxon-c

I'm building a report that will show the line numbers of XML elements that match a set of XPaths. I need to support XPath 2.0. Sending the XML to a separate web based processor written in Java or C# is a valid solution, but one I'm avoiding because my entire team works in Python, I want my tool to still work offline, and maintaining another web service is a lot of work.

Saxonche supports XPath 2.0. The [documentation](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc12/html/saxonc.html#PyDocumentBuilder) describes multiple options for enabling line numbers, but never explains how to get the line numbers out once you have enabled them.

Here's my code:

```
input_file_path = 'test.xml'  # Contents below
input_xpath = './/foo'

with PySaxonProcessor(license=False) as saxon_proc:

    # Attempt #1 to enable line numbers
    saxon_proc.set_configuration_property('l', 'on')  

    doc_builder = saxon_proc.new_document_builder()
    # Attempt #2 to enable line numbers
    doc_builder.set_line_numbering(True)

    xml_tree = doc_builder.parse_xml(xml_file_name=input_file_path)
    xpath_processor = saxon_proc.new_xpath_processor()
    xpath_processor.set_context(xdm_item=xml_tree)

    foo_elements = xpath_processor.evaluate(input_xpath)
    # Do not see any line numbers on foo_elements in the debugger
```

I inspected the result of `evaluate()` in the debugger, but I don't see anything that looks like a line number.

[image: debugger inspect]

Both `PySaxonProcessor` and `PyDocumentBuilder` have a `parse_xml()` method. In my code I am using `PyDocumentBuilder`, but I tried both and didn't notice any differences.

test.XML

```
<root>
    <foo>fah</foo>
</root>
```

Apparently there are [wrong ways to feed your XML to Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58455579/3224483) that can result in no line numbers, but all of the information I found about that is in other languages.

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can set the line numbering via the configuration as follows:
`saxon_proc.set_configuration_property('http://saxon.sf.net/feature/linenumbering', 'on')`. but you are right getting them out is not so easy via the API I don't think there is an API method on XdmNode to get the line number. I have create a bug issue for this on our bug tracker https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/6351. As Martin mentioned in the first soluation you can use `saxon:line-number` in a xpath to get the line number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid I can't currently tell there is a way for SaxonC HE, for PE/EE you should be able to use the Saxon XPath extension function `saxon:line-number` e.g.

```
from saxoncee import PySaxonProcessor

with PySaxonProcessor(license=True) as saxon_proc:
    print(saxon_proc.version)

    doc_builder = saxon_proc.new_document_builder()
    doc_builder.set_line_numbering(True)

    xdm_doc = doc_builder.parse_xml(xml_file_name='sample1.xml')

    xpath_processor = saxon_proc.new_xpath_processor()

    xpath_processor.set_context(xdm_item=xdm_doc)

    xpath_processor.declare_namespace('saxon', 'http://saxon.sf.net/')

    items = xpath_processor.evaluate('//item')

    for item in items:
        xpath_processor.set_context(xdm_item=item)
        print(item, xpath_processor.evaluate_single('saxon:line-number(.)'))
```

As I said, I am currently not sure whether there is a way for SaxonC HE, will try to investigate, https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc12/html/saxonc.html#PyXdmNode, however, doesn't seem to expose any properties similar to the Java API's XdmNode's https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmNode.html#getLineNumber().

Comment: I have created the bug issue to add line numbering for PyXdmNode: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/6351