Will SaxonC-EE work even without a valid license?
I installed saxoncee 12.4.2 version in my local using the "pip install saxoncee" command and used it for xml transformation. As per the documentation, SaxonC-EE is an Enterprise edition package and requires a license file to be provided in a specific path, but I was able to run it successfully in my local with license=True set in the code and without any specific license file provided. Am I missing something or is there possibilities for SaxonC-EE to run without an explicit license file?
Code language used is Python.

It might run as HE, so no streaming, schema support etc. But I haven't checked

The general intent -- I'm not sure how much testing we have done -- is that if you use the SaxonEE software without a license file, it falls back to SaxonHE functionality. (But not for SaxonCS, which is currently EE-only).

@Michael Kay,I got a 30 day evaluation license, provided it in the home directory where saxonC-EE is installed in my local and tried to test it. The xml transformation works fine but I'm unable to figure out if it's using the license file or it's simply running in saxonC-HE functionality. Is there any way that I can verify if the license file is used. Code language: Python

Run any code trying to use a(n extension) function only available in PE or EE, like the sample in https://stackoverflow.com/a/78009287/252228, if the code works it is the licensed version that is run, if you get an error that the extension function is not found the license is not set up correctly. See https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation12/index.html#!starting/licensing for details, you can set an environment variable SAXONC_HOME for instance for your license file directory.

We are using the below command to include the license file for saxonC-EE in python. proc.set_configuration_property("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/licenseFileLocation","saxonceefilepath/saxon-license.lic"). But somehow the license is not getting recognized. Could you please let us know if this is the right way to use or are we missing something?

Please provide the full code you use and tell us which platform you are on. It might be better to do that in a new question, telling us exactly how  "somehow the license is not getting recognized"  manifests itself in your case.

The code you have shown in the comment got somehow mangled so it is hard to tell what you tried exactly but it is certainly possible to use e.g. saxon_proc.set_configuration_property('http://saxon.sf.net/feature/licenseFileLocation', '/home/mh/saxon-license.lic').

The code that you have mentioned in the previous comment is exactly the same that we tried earlier, but the license was not recognized. Is there anything else to be added?

I don't think you need to add anything in terms of Python code. But if you want us to help find out why the license is not recognized you need to provide more details and/or context. Or perhaps contact Saxonica's support via their support email (you should have got that with the license) and let them try to resolve it, here on StackOverflow it will be hard to exchange a repro if license files are involved.

Okay sure, let me try to check with Saxonica's support.Thanks.

hi, just checking if you managed to resolve your issue with locating license file? Do you have code snippet with more that just the set_configuration_property?
